# Internal error 500 with framework Silex

Tags: php, .htaccess, silex, internal-server-error

I'm new, and i'm french, so excuse me for my english.
I'm a beginner in developement.
I use at home wamp for my host, phpStorm for edit and Silex framework to do my website.
On my computer it's ok, i see my page, no problem. But when I post it in OVH (online host), I have an error 500. 
in the beginning I don't have an .htaccess, and when I create it, I have the same problem.

Please help me. Talk with me in french if you can, or english and I will understand.

Thank's my friends

Comment: For the record your english is pretty good.

Comment: As I think @T.AKROUT is saying, you should check your web server's log to get a clue of what may be the error. You should post it if you pretend to get help, otherwise it's very difficult to help you

Comment: Thank's for responses, I don't find log file, my Host is very complicated, when I found it I post it here. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases after installing Silex you might get 500 Error because Silex doesn't have right to write in `cache` folder, which it uses for f.ex. Twig. You need to add rights with using `chmod`

Cache file is located under /var, so command below should help:

In Silex root directory:

```
chmod 777 -R var/
```

---

**Check for errors**

If you are using Apache, log files should be stored there:

```
/var/log/apache2/
```

To check what errors just occured you can look inside a file just with:

```
cat error.log
```

It happened to me also, I've got error (which cause 500 - Internal server error):

> Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create
>   the cache directory (config/../var/cache/twig/d0)

And steps above fixed it.

---

**Manuals**

[CHMOD [FR]](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

[CHMOD [EN]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)